# How can I find specific words in the file?

Tags: c

I want to check if the words "Title1, title2, title 3, title4" are in the file.
If these words are available in the file, I want to print "we found the% s word in file".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

char word[4][20]={"tittle1","tittle2","tittle3","tittle4"};
char *string;
int k;
FILE *in_file = fopen("abce.txt", "r");


if (in_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error file missing\n");

}

else{


printf("enter a array number that you want find in file");
scanf("%d",&k);

    while(!feof(in_file))
    {
        fscanf(in_file,"%s",string);
        if(!strcmp(string,word[k-1])){
            printf("we found the word %s in the file \n",string );

}
}

}
return 0;
 }
```

But I can't write the code correctly.
Can you help me fix it? Thanks for your help...

Comment: plus your while loop while(word[0]!= '0') will never stop.. why would you check word[0] ? check your input instead

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a bit of refactoring.

`string` is `char *` but never allocated. Thus, the `fscanf` would segfault.

`word` could be `char *word[]`.

Your `strcmp` needs to be connected to the `printf`

You need to `rewind` the file before scanning it for each new word.

Other fixes ...

Anyway, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *word[] = { "tittle1", "tittle2", "tittle3", "tittle4" };
    char string[1000];
    int k;
    FILE *in_file = fopen("abce.txt", "r");

    if (in_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error file missing\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("enter a array number that you want find in file: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &k);

        if (k < 0)
            break;

        if (k >= (sizeof(word) / sizeof(word[0]))) {
            printf("invalid index -- %d\n",k);
            continue;
        }

        rewind(in_file);
        int wordidx = 0;
        while (1) {
            if (fscanf(in_file, " %s", string) != 1)
                break;
            //printf("DEBUG: '%s'\n",string);

            if (strcmp(string, word[k]) == 0) {
                printf("we found the word '%s' in the file at offset %d\n",
                    word[k],wordidx);
                break;
            }

            ++wordidx;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```